# Ajax url not properly parse on some mobile browsers

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a simple form with ajax navigation.

My .htaccess file has redirects. So "next" redirects to "next.php".

My form:

```
<form action="next">
```

My Ajax onSubmit looks like this (partial code shown for brevity. The function fires fine):

```
var url  = $(this).attr('action');
function formSubmit($data,$url){
                $.ajax({
                    url: $url,
                    data: $data
```

Redirect Code:

```
if(response.next){                          
   window.location.href=response.next;
}
```

What happens is...most browser redirect fine. The url that is called in order to obtain the redirect URL is:

```
http://example.com/next
```

But some (such as windows mobile as tested through http://mobiletest.me/) append the url so that the following page is attempted to be loaded via ajax.

```
http://example.com/http://example.com/next
```

Why? And how do I fix this?

Comment: Where is the redirect code....

Comment: I added it above, but it doesn't matter because the the redirect URL never gets returned because the action url isn't loaded....that's the focus of the question.

Comment: So does the Ajax call get made? I am not sure what your problem is. If it does succeed,  what is the value in `response.next`?

Comment: the call  does not get made because the URL for the call is not correct. I'm wondering now if it's a bug in mobiletest.me's windows phone implementation.

Comment: What URL is not correct? There are two there...The url for the Ajax call or the url for the window.location???